# Resolving same maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have a  java project where i use folowing library

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.java-websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>Java-WebSocket</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

Also i use signalr library and it has next dependency in your pom

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.java-websocket</groupId>
      <artifactId>Java-WebSocket</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.7</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

When i run my code i get this erorr

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/java_websocket/drafts/Draft_6455  at
>   com.github.signalr4j.client.transport.AutomaticTransport.initialize(AutomaticTransport.java:62)
>     at
>   com.github.signalr4j.client.transport.AutomaticTransport.(AutomaticTransport.java:44)
>     at com.github.signalr4j.client.Connection.start(Connection.java:273)

I've tried excluded dependency from signalr library

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.signalr4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>signalr4j</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
<exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>Java-WebSocket</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.java-websocket</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

but it didn't work.

Is any thouths what i'm doing wrong?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change *your* dependency to version 1.3.7. The signalr4j library needs version 1.3.7.

Comment: I've tried this too. But my code don't work with version 1.3.7. Only with 1.3.0.

Comment: You can only have one version of a dependency at a time (unless you're ready for classloader magic and then it's still a question whether you can get it to work). You can try to find an older version of signalr4j that works with 1.3.0, or you upgrade your own code to work with 1.3.7, or you stop using signal4j altogether.

Comment: I understand. Thanks a lot.